# Get a notification when the user gets a SMS

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to get a notification for my app when the user gets a SMS, then I want to display the sms in a tableview. I've read somewhere that it is possible, even though the app will be likely to get rejected from the App Store. Still I'd like to know how to do that. Any help is really appreciated, I can't find anything about how to do that.

Comment: Where did you read that it was possible? That would be a good place to start.

Comment: it was a few weeks ago, I can't find the link anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone is facing the same problem, here is how you do it:

1. Check if the device is jailbroken:

   ```
   NSString *filePath = @"/Applications/Cydia.app";

   if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
       //do something here
   }
   ```
2. Open the SQLite database:
   `/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db`
3. Read the `message` table.